# How do I display how many tamed cats each player has on the scoreboard?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Can someone help me with a command that makes a scoreboard to the right of the screen that show's how many cats someone has tamed/has with them?

Answer (score 2):

I have not found a way that you set up once and that then works for every player. You can however do this, but it does require some additional steps for each player

**You have to do these steps once, you do not have to do them again**

First you can create a scoreboard objective and set it to the sidebar, these do not require command blocks:

```
/scoreboard objectives add catCount dummy "Cats Tamed"
/scoreboard objectives setdisplay sidebar catCount
```

Then you set up a repeating command block with the command

```
/scoreboard players set @a catCount 0
```

**This is what you do for EVERY player:**

Get the player ID, I have not found a good way to get it from within the game. You can tame a cat and go close to it and use this (the easier way, but it may give you the wrong ID if the wrong person has tamed the cat, or if there are multiple cats nearby):

```
/data get entity @e[type=cat,limit=1,distance=..5] OwnerUUID
```

You can also get it by navigating to `C:\Users\<your name>\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\saves\<the name of your world>\playerdata` on your computer and copying the filename of **your** data (or whoever you may want to add).

Once you have it you place a chain command block where the repeating command block is pointing at (there will be arrows on it), directly next to it, while making sure the new command blocks points in the same direction.

To add more players simply make a longer chain with command blocks

Put this command into the chain command block:

```
/execute as @e[type=cat,nbt={OwnerUUID:<player id of the player you want to add>}] run scoreboard players add <player you want to add> catCount 1
```

A setup for 5 players may look like this:

[image]

I recommend to make the blue command block require redstone and use a lever and the green ones to be "always active", but you can also set all of them to "always active", in which case you do not need a lever.

Comment: Depending on what you want you can also put "`execute at @e[type=cat,nbt=!{OwnerUUID:""}] as @a[distance=..10] run scoreboard players add @s catCount 1`" into your first chain command block, then you would not need any more chain command blocks and it would work for every player. It does only count how many tamed cats there are nearby every player. This does not detect who tamed the cat and one cat can be counted twice, or more, if more than one person is close to it.